# Windows 11 Microsoft Edge Bookmarks Location

Tags: microsoft-edge, bookmarks, windows-11, favorites, microsoft-edge-chromium

I am wanting to create a PowerShell script that will run on a Task Scheduler schedule to back up my Windows 11 Microsoft Edge bookmarks. All the references I can find say that the location of the bookmark file is in `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks`. However, inside the User Data folder, there is no Default folder.

Some online searches reference the DBStore in `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge`... however, the only folder listed in AC is Temp.

I have plenty of Favorites shown in my browser but cannot find the file they are stored in so that I can back up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested the scenario and found that on Windows-11 OS, MS Edge stores bookmarks on the location below for a Default profile.

`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default`

[image]

You could see I have added **Test1** in the Bookmark bar, which I could see in the Bookmarks file.

[image]

If you are using multiple profiles and you are looking for bookmarks you added under that profile then you need to look into folder for that specific profile.

For example, `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Profile 1`

If you are not able to see the Bookmarks file, it means that you have not added the bookmarks for that profile.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find the location according to your answer. The location is C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Profile 1